# Java how can i add this? Where Python have already

Tags: java, preview

I would like to do the same with Java. Any idea if we have such for Java? To work in cross platform specially in Linux/Bsd/Mac.

example: http://www.chromium.org/developers/testing/pyauto

- i want to take screen shot of a website and show a preview like ( http://www.google.com shows site preview)

Comment: thats nice to `like` but i have no idea what your talking about, would u like fries with that?

Comment: question is not clear. If you want platform transparency. You can achieve it with Python as mentioned in the LINK you pasted!?

Comment: Java wants to use Chromium. But there is no such except webKit, and chromium also dont provide anything else for Java.

Comment: Well these are the issues, i want to move to D language. Because Java is not even open source and you have not yet a strong fast, challenging browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp) project is one place to start looking for a Java HTML renderer.

Comment: Thats too slow for heavy traffic and heavy site preview capture.

Comment: Its not really relevent compared to Chromium description and embed.